How to add class to td only if text in that td and other td are present
I need to add a new class to a td (the first in the code below), but with two conditions: only if that td has a specific number on it (for example "2"), and if the next td also has some text on it (for example "6oz").
The need to add this new class, is because I will use it to count the total of units that meet the conditions mentioned above. (2 and 6oz for example)
I have a big limitation, I have several tr in the code, and I can not modify the initial code, so it won't be possible to identify the tr (in the code below).
Thanks in advance for any help!!  I'll really appreciate your advice.
<tr>
  <td class="a-text-center">2</td>
  <td class="a-text-left">
      <span class="a-text-bold">bottle 6oz</span> <br>
      <div class="a-row"> 
        <span class="a-text-bold"> Condition: </span> <span> New </span> 
      </div></td>
</tr>


What have you tried? When should the class be added?

We expect that you'll make an attempt and post what you've tried in your question, along with any error messages you may have gotten.

why do you need to first add the class and then count? you can directly iterate on the trs and count if the two conditions are met

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. Why not simply count the rows that meet these conditions. Adding a new class is just an extra step.

You can give the following a try, see if the following adds the class in the way you are expecting (using jQuery as mentioned in the tag):
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    const firstTd = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)');
    const secondTd = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)');

    if (firstTd.length && secondTd.length) {
      const firstTdText = $.trim(firstTd.text());
      const secondTdText = $.trim(secondTd.text());

      if (firstTdText === '2' && secondTdText.includes('6oz')) {
        firstTd.addClass('new-class');
      }
    }
  });
});


It works like a charm!!  You are the man!  Thanks!

I'm glad it worked well for you!
